# How to get the same instance from the autofac scope?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, autofac

Using Autofac, In my ASP .NET Web API application I'm resolving service on multiple places (Web API filter, query interceptor under EF6).

In WebAPI filter I'm resolving my service and setting up some property under the same resolved object.

Later in EF6 interceptor, again, I'm resolving the same service, asking for a values previously changed in WebAPI filter.

What I've noticed that in query interceptor resolved object has different hashcode than one resolved in Web API fiter.

I've also tried to change the values using InjectProperties method.

Global.asax code

```
builder.RegisterType<MyType>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
```

Web API code

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  var service = scope.Resolve<IService>();
  service.A = "test";
  //service.GetHashCode() - 111111
}
```

EF6 Query Interceptor

```
//I'm getting here different hashcode, service.A is null.
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  var service = scope.Resolve<IService>();
  var a = service.A; //service.A here is null (string).
 //service.GetHashCode() - 222222
}
```

How to get the same instance, or at least the new one but with all changes made in Web API filter.

Comment: Just a guess, but you should change the `InstancePerRequest` to `SingleInstance`

Comment: I can't. Object being used is per loggedin user.

Comment: Have you tried InstancePerLifetimeScope ?

Comment: It has same effect as **InstancePerRequest**, also I'm getting some unwanted side effects. Btw, I don' have a problem with resolving in general. I have a problem with getting data from some other resolvings.

Comment: Use `InstanceByMatchingLifetimeScope("yourscopename")` and give both of your scopes the same name (`BeginLifetimeScope("yourscopename")`), so Autofac knows which scopes are the same. See https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-matching-lifetime-scope for details.

Comment: @ckuri if that's the solution, he could use the HttpContext.Current.SessionID.